# How to make readonly views in grails?

Tags: grails, readonly, gsp

Some of my domain classes represent static data and they are not allowed to be modified. How can I make sure at the UI level that grails automatically prevents users from modifying data.

In simple words, I need to create readonly views for some of my domain classes. Is it possible to mark a domain class as readonly?

Comment: could you please provide a more complete example, what you are after?  is this question about scaffolded UIs?

Comment: @cfrick : I have an Exchange domain class which represents stock exchanges around the world. This data is static and users are not allowed to add/delete/update this data.

class Exchange {
    String code;
    String name;
}

I need scaffolding to make readonly views, which means (Option to create/modify/delete should not be present on generated views.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a contraint that you can set on your properties for scaffolding to set them as *readonly* :

> editable :    Boolean that determines whether the property can be edited
>   from the scaffolding views. If false, the associated form fields are
>   displayed in read-only mode.

As per this [link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html)

Else you can generate the static scaffolding controller and views and remove the create/update/delete actions and view components.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this grails does make the fields readonly when I go to edit my domain. But my purpose is to get rid of the "Create, Edit & Delete" buttons which are present on the view. So that all a user can do is "List & View" data.

Comment: I can generate views and manually edit them to get my job done, but I really feel scaffolding should support this. I might be missing something.

Comment: You can add the scaffolding templates to your project and edit them via the "install-templates" command (http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) You can then add code in the template to check for something on your domain class (like a static editable = false property) to prevent the controller and view stuff to be generated. You could also make a pull request in the scaffolding plugin as I think this feature would be a nice addon to Grails.